# Flex SWFLOADER.CONTENT weird

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder4.5, flashbuilder4

Following creation complete event not working on remote server.Working fine on local.

enter code here

```
    protected function completed():void
                {
                    myloader.visible=true;
                    //clearInterval(interval);
                    Alert.show("Timer");
                    Alert.show("Timer"+myloader.content);
                    var mc:AVM1Movie=AVM1Movie(myloader.content);
                    mc.x=-189;
                    mc.y=0;
                    mc.scaleX=0.75;
                    mc.scaleY=0.65;

                }
```

i am loading facebook video.
I have set crossdomain.xml also set allowscriptaccess and allownetworking .Please somebody help if i missed something here

Comment: Make sure `AVM1Movie` is an interface not class and is the same exactly on both sides. and as @mgraph wrote - if it is a listener it has to have adequate signature.

Comment: hi Tomasz Gawel Thanks for reply .The problem is with myloader.content only. Alert.show("Timer"+myloader.content); this line not executed.Getting first timer alert alone.Second one not shown anything. I have tried mgraph comments already.can you send me your email id i ll send entire code

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
protected function completed(event:*):void
                {
```